# function "fwrite" write incorrect content

Tags: php, arrays, include, fwrite

I have file (filename: inc.php) with code in site:

```
<?php 
$menu['Position1']['menu1'][]='module1'; 
$menu['Position1']['menu2'][]='module2';
?>
```

I want change code of this file to add new node array to it. then I test simple code:

```
include 'inc.php';

//add new value to array
$menu['Position3']['menu3'][]='module3'; 
$menu['Position4']['menu4'][]='module4';

//create string with fomat above
$text ='<?php ' ."\n";
foreach($menu as $position_tmp => $value1_tmp){
foreach($value1_tmp as $menu_tmp => $value2_tmp){
foreach($value2_tmp as $component_tmp){
$text .= "\$menu['" .$position_tmp ."']['" .$menu_tmp ."'][]='" .$component_tmp ."'; \n";
}
}
}
$text .= '?>';
```

Then I test $text. var_dump($text); output:

```
<?php 
$menu['Position1']['menu1'][]='module1'; 
$menu['Position1']['menu2'][]='module2';
$menu['Position3']['menu3'][]='module3'; 
$menu['Position4']['menu4'][]='module4';
?>
```

It's OK. I write to file inc.php:

```
$fp = fopen('inc.php', 'w+');
fwrite($fp,$text);
fclose($fp);
```

Content of inc.php:

```
<?php 
$menu['Position1']['menu1'][]='module1'; 
$menu['Position1']['menu2'][]='module2';
$menu['Position3']['menu3'][]='module3';
$menu['Position3']['menu3'][]='module3';
$menu['Position3']['menu3'][]='module3';
$menu['Position4']['menu4'][]='module4';
$menu['Position4']['menu4'][]='module4';
$menu['Position4']['menu4'][]='module4';
?>
```

I don't know why!
Then I test write new file: newfile.php. Then content of newfile.php is correct.

```
<?php 
$menu['Position1']['menu1'][]='module1'; 
$menu['Position1']['menu2'][]='module2';
$menu['Position3']['menu3'][]='module3'; 
$menu['Position4']['menu4'][]='module4';
?>
```

I try delete inc.php, rename newfile.php to inc.php

```
sleep(5); // I open newfile.php. It's correct.
unlink('inc.php');
rename('newfile.php','inc.php');
```

inc.php still incorrect. I can't understand. Please to help me!

Comment: "I try delete inc.php, rename newfile.php to inc.php 
sleep(5); // I open newfile.php. It's correct.
unlink('inc.php');
rename('newfile.php','inc.plist.php');

inc.php still incorrect. I can't understand. Please to help me!"          Are you sure of your rename instruction ?

Comment: I'm sorry, don't have ".plist" in new file name. That code is:rename('newfile.php','inc.php');

Answer (score 0):

Appending `'<?php'` string with your $text will cause a problem. Better to use:

```
$php_open_tag    = htmlentities('<?php'); // Or try like this htmlspecialchars('<?php');
$php_close_tag   = htmlentities('?>');
$text = $php_open_tag . 'YOUR CONTENT' . $php_close_tag ;
$text = str_replace('&lt;','<',$text);
$text = str_replace('&gt;','>',$text);
```

and then try to write your content.

```
$fp = fopen('inc.php', 'w+');
fwrite($fp,$text);
fclose($fp);
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it's still incorrect. Thank you again!